# Makefile Target Pattern with %

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, target

I am new to makefile.
All I want is, when a specific C file will be changed, I want to run one command. And finally from one folder, any of the C file will be changed then I want to run the same command with that filename.
.e.g.

```
ceedling test:filename
```

I have simple file called unittest.mk. I am not sure the following approach is correct or not. 
I am ruinning the following command to run this file.

> make -f unittest.mk StartUnitTest

Here is the unittest.mk file:

```
TEST_OBJS += \
    D:\ModApp\Apps\Paymark\ModApp_Paymark\build\test\out\test_txn_admin.o

D:\ModApp\Apps\Paymark\ModApp_Paymark\build\test\out\test_txn_admin.o: D:\ModApp\Apps\Paymark\ModApp_Paymark\test\test_txn_admin.c
    echo $(*F)
    echo $@
    echo $<

StartUnitTest:
    @echo Start Unit Test
    $(TEST_OBJS)
    @echo End Unit Test
```

When I run this file, it is giving the following error.

```
Start Unit Test
D:\ModApp\Apps\Paymark\ModApp_Paymark\build\test\out\test_txn_admin.o
D:\ModApp\Apps\Paymark\ModApp_Paymark\build\test\out\test_txn_admin.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(D:\ModApp\Apps\Paymark\ModApp_Paymark\build\test\out\test_txn_admin.o, D:\ModApp\Apps\Paymark\ModApp_Paymark\build\test\out\test_txn_admin.o, ...) failed.
make (e=193): Error 193
make: *** [StartUnitTest] Error 193
```

Finally once this will work, actually I want a target pattern with % as the following:

```
D:\ModApp\Apps\Paymark\ModApp_Paymark\build\test\out\%.o: D:\ModApp\Apps\Paymark\ModApp_Paymark\test\%.c
    echo $(*F)
    echo $@
    echo $<
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: Please edit your question and put the command you typed and the error you got in the question, where it can be properly formatted, not in a comment where it's just a blob of text.  However I don't see any reason why, if your first makefile works, your second one wouldn't.

Comment: I have shifted error in the main question.

Comment: There is no way that that error is being generated from that rule in the makefile.  As you can see when it prints the recipe it is printing just the object file name, not the `cd ../../ ...` which means clearly make is choosing a different recipe.  There is some other part of your makefile that you haven't shown us which is causing this.  I recommend you run `make -d` and examine the output.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for reply. You are right, something is wrong in our makefile. To avoid the complexity, I have created one simple file but it is giving error. I have added this simple file in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue. I have changed the target "StartUnitTest" to the following and it is working now. Removed the echo messages.

```
StartUnitTest: $(TEST_OBJS)
```

Thank you MadScientist. the "make -d" does helped me to find the issue.

Comment: Definitely: in your recipe for the `StartUnitTest` (which you didn't show us originally) you list `$(TEST_OBJS)`.  That is expanded to a list of object files then passed to the shell (command.com) to run as if it were a program; that's what recipes are: commands that are run to build things.  A list of object files is not a valid program, so you get an error.

Comment: Yes, now I get it. Other than that your suggestion of using "make -d" helped me to track the sequence of calling. As I didn't know that we can do that. Thank you one again.